# Как корректно инициализировать компонент в Vue?

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Вводная:
никакие системы сборки не используются

Имеем:
На страницу подключен vue

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Подключен этот компонент https://github.com/dbrekalo/vue-date-pick/blob/master/dist/vueDatePick.js (так же через script)
HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<date-pick
            v-model="date"
            :pick-time="true"
            :selectable-year-range="{ from: 2000, to: 2020 }"
            :format="'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'">
    </date-pick>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app,
        data: {
            date: ''
        },
        components: {
            'date-pick': VueDatePick
        }
    })
```

Проблема:
В общем - то это работает, но нет возможности переиспользовать компонент: если вставить

```
<date-pick v-model="date"></date-pick>
```

на страницу дважды, то контент будет идентичный и это понятно почему - надо передать в компонент

```
data: function(){
 return {
date: ''
}
}
```

а не в объект data самого экземпляра vue

И вот как это сделать - не пойму

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы использовать `v-model` вам необходимо сделать пропс у компонента `value`. И эимтнуть событие `input`. `v-model` - это двунаправленная связь.

Пример (вам необходимо сделать на подобии):

```js
Vue.component('select-city', {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  template: `
      <div>
        <span
         @click="emit"
        >
          {{ value }}
        </span>
      </div>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {

    emit(event) {
      this.$emit('input', ++ this.counter);

      return this;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      counter_1: 0,
      counter_2: 0,
      counter_3: 0,
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.block {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: aquamarine;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="block">
    <select-city
      v-model="counter_1"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <select-city
      v-model="counter_2"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <select-city
      v-model="counter_3"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Подробнее об использовании [`v-model` в собственных компонентах](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-model-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85).

Answer (score 0):

Остановился на таком варианте

HTML

```
<date-pick v-model="date1"></date-pick>
<date-pick v-model="date2"></date-pick>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            date1: '',
            date2: '',
        },
        components: {
            'date-pick': VueDatePick
        }
    })
```